# Why in Quran 6:101 Allah says He can't have a child without mate?

Tags: quran, allah, monotheism

I read a christian argument that keeping aside the concept of actions befitting his glory if he wills to do something then there should be no limitations and he doesn't need to be like creation. It seems like God his making self a human and saying he needs a spouse to have a son. Why quran depicts begetting only as sexual activity which we don't or perhaps pagans would also haven't believed?

Answer (score 2):

Allah specifically mentions not having a mate to conceive a child because the Christians believe Mary is the mother of Jesus AND god is the father of Jesus, hence why they say “Jesus Christ is the son of God”.

They believe that the Holy Spirit had intercourse with Mary to impregnate Mary with Jesus.

(Though it’s a little more complicated than that since they also say Joseph is Jesus’s dad).

Matthew 1:18-25 says:

> “Now the birth of Jesus the Messiah took place in this way. When his mother Mary had been engaged to Joseph, but before they lived together, she was found to be with child from the Holy Spirit.”

In the Qur’an chapter 17 verse 111 it says:

> “And say, "Praise to Allah, who has not taken a son and has had no partner in [His] dominion and has no [need of a] protector out of weakness; and glorify Him with [great] glorification.”

Allah is telling us that what the Christians believe about the birth of Jesus is wrong. Allah is far above having a son and in no way has ever had a mate to conceive Jesus because he doesn’t have a son.
Jesus was born miraculously from the Virgin Mary (like the Christians believe as well, but the irony is, Mary in Christianity was touched by a man (and spirit for that matter) while the Mary in Islam was not).

In the Qur’an chapter 3 verses 45-51 it says:

> “(And mention) when the angels said, ‘O Mary, indeed God gives you the
> good news of a word from Him, whose name will be the Messiah Jesus,
> the son of Mary, held in honor in this world and in the Hereafter, and
> of those who are near to God.’  ‘He will speak to the people in the
> cradle, and in old age, and he will be of the righteous.’  She said,
> ‘My Lord, how can I have a son when no man has touched me.’  He said,
> ‘So (it will be,) for God creates what He wants.  When He decides
> something, He only says to it, ‘Be,’ and it is.  And He will teach him
> the Book and wisdom and the Torah and the Gospel.  And (will make him)
> a messenger to the Children of Israel (saying), ‘Indeed I have come to
> you with a sign from your Lord.  I make for you out of clay the
> likeness of a bird, then breathe into it, and it becomes a bird by the
> permission of God.  And I heal the blind and the leper, and I bring
> the dead to life by the permission of God.  And I inform you of what
> you eat and what you store in your houses.  Surely, there is a sign
> for you in that, if you are believers.  And (I have come) confirming
> the Torah that was (revealed) before me, and to allow you some of what
> was forbidden to you.  And I have come to you with a proof from your
> Lord, so fear God and obey me.  Indeed, God is my Lord and your Lord,
> so worship Him.  This is the straight path.”

Answer (score 0):

Allah is unique and there is no other comparable to him. If He had a son, then He would not be unique, because the His son would be comparable to Him, but Allah is unique, and this is why He has no son.

@Epistemophile.Bibliophile, you have made some errors in your answer. Though Christians believe that Mary is the mother of Jesus, they believe that Jesus has existed eternally, and that Jesus was the Son of God before Mary existed. They believe that the Holy Spirit **did not have** intercourse with Mary. They believe that Joseph was Jesus' stepfather.

Most Christians believe that Mary was a perpetual virgin throughout her entire life, however most Protestant Christians believe that Mary had intercourse with Joseph **after** Jesus was born.